# Convergence rate of log likelihood ratio

Tags: self-study, convergence, likelihood-ratio

I have come across the following statement in the textbook [A course on Large Sample Theory by Ferguson](https://books.google.com.sg/books/about/A_Course_in_Large_Sample_Theory.html?id=DDh_OiTw9agC&redir_esc=y) - Chapter 17. Strong Consistency of the Maximum Likelihood Estimates.

> The likelihood ratio, $L_n(\theta)/ L_n(\theta_0)$  converges to zero
> exponentially fast, at a rate $\text{exp}\{-nK(\theta_0,\theta)\}$

Here, $L_n$ is the likelihood function, $\theta_0$ is the true parameter of the distribution from which data was sampled, $\theta$ is an estimate of the true parameter and $K$ is the KL-divergence between the true distribution and fitted distribution.

The reasoning for the statement was given as follows:

From Weak Law of Large Numbers, we have
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{n} \log \frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)} &=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \log \frac{L_{i}(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_{i}\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0\right)} \\
& \stackrel{\mathrm{P}}{\longrightarrow}-\mathrm{K}\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 ,\boldsymbol{\theta}\right), \\
\text{i.e.}\qquad  \frac{1}{n} \log \frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)} + \mathrm{K}\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 ,\boldsymbol{\theta}\right) &= o_p(1)
\end{aligned}

I am trying to understand how the above statement on this exponential convergence follows from this convergence in probability.

Here is my attempt where I proceed from the reverse direction:

I need to prove that

\begin{align}
& \frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)}  = o_p(-\text{exp}\{-nK (\theta_0,\theta)\}) \\
\implies  & \frac{\frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)}}{\text{exp}\{-nK (\theta_0,\theta)\}} = o_p(1)  \\ & \text{and because log is a continuous function}, \qquad
   \log \frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)} + nK (\theta_0,\theta) = o_p(1) \\ 
& \text{in other words, I need to establish}  \qquad \frac{1}{n} \log \frac{L_n(\boldsymbol{\theta})}{L_n\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_0 \right)} + K (\theta_0,\theta) = o_p(1/n)
\end{align}

As you can see, I need a convergence order of $o_p(1/n)$, however, from WLLN, I have only $o_p(1)$. How do I proceed from here? Also, in general, is this approach correct? Are there any other ways to prove the same?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: Appreciate your suggestion to add the self-study tag; added it now. Also, I did provide my attempt and indicated where I am stuck in my original post. Let me know if something was not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the Law of Large Numbers
$$\frac{1}{n}\log\frac{L_n(\theta)}{L_n(\theta_0)} = -K_n(\theta_0,\theta)+o_p(1)$$
so
$$\log\frac{L_n(\theta)}{L_n(\theta_0)} = -nK_n(\theta_0,\theta)+o_p(n)$$

And that's all we need: the term that's proportional to $n$ dominates the $o_p(n)$ term.

If you want the epsilontics: write $r_n$ for the $o_p(n)$ term.  For every finite $M$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for $n>N$
$$P(r_n<Mn)>1-\epsilon.$$
Choose $M=K_n(\theta_0,\theta)/2$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for $n>N$
$$P\left(-nK_n(\theta_0,\theta)+r_n< -nK_n(\theta_0,\theta)/2\right)>1-\epsilon$$
so
$$P\left( \frac{L_n(\theta)}{L_n(\theta_0)}<\exp\left(-nK_n(\theta_0,\theta)/2 \right) \right)>1-\epsilon$$